# Add custom headers to crossbrowser requests

Tags: nginx, header

We have an issue with our API implementation.We are implementing APIs using Slim Framework ,PHP in Nginx Servers
Suppose we implement our api in domain api.mydomain.com and we try to send GET,POST,PUT request to domains like services.mydomain.com or apps.mydomain.com.Our requests are need to be add custom headers for 'x-api-key' and 'x-session-key' for security.But using jquery when we try to add in any methods we cant able to send requests to different domain. We tried it by adding both ways

headers: { 'X_API_KEY' : varibaleName.apiSecretKey },
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');},

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: secretIdUrl,
                    type:'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    //headers: { 'X_API_KEY' : varibaleName.apiSecretKey },
                    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');},
              dataType: "json",

                success: function (data) {          
                         if(data.results){
                              widgetControl.setSecretID(data.results.id);
                         }
                }
            });
```

Can you please guide us to resolve this issue in client side in ajax requests if you have experience in similar issues

References :
http://enable-cors.org
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dom-access-control-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X_API_KEY'; # and all headers ', ' separated
}
```

More of add_header: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule#add_header